# Can someone identify this Lepidoptera larva?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology, lepidoptera

That's from Brazilian Amazon, more specifically a small mountain (300 m high) called "Morro dos Seis Lagos" (six lakes hill), at São Gabriel da Cachoeira municipality, Amazonas state, located at 0.283 North, 66.685 West.

[image: Lepidoptera larva]

Comment: Can you add an approximate size? 2-3cm?

Comment: @RHA Sorry, it's been 14 long years now. But I think bigger than that, between 5 and 10 cm.